# I want to equal an user input to an answer and print according to user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am creating a math test program that creates random questions and I ask the user to input the answer and the answer is checked with the correct answer and the output is given.

```py
import random
q = 1
live=3
operations = ("+" , "-")
for q in range(0,11):
    while live>=1:
        op=random.choice(operations)
        num1=random.randint(0,10)
        num2=random.randint(1,10)
        if op =="+":
            op=random.choice(operations)
            num1=random.randint(0,10)
            num2=random.randint(1,10)
            correct = num1+num2
            print("What is", " " +str(num1) + "+" +str(num2) + "?")
            answer =input("\n Enter answer")
            if answer==correct :
                print("Correct answer")
                q= q+1
            else:
                answer != correct
                live= live - 1
                print("The answer is incorrect. Try again mate!")
```

this is my incomplete code. The problem is even when there is a question with the addition mark and the user inputs the correct answer the programs still prints the wrong output (the output that should be printed if the user enters a wrong answer) Please, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
answer = input("\n Enter answer")
```

To this:

```
answer = int(input("\n Enter answer"))
```

The reason being is that your comparing a `str` and an `int`.

**For Example**

In the case of`num1 = 5` and `num2 = 5`

- `correct` will be equal to `5+5` or `10`.
- However, `answer` will be equal to the string `"10"`.

So when you go to test equality between `correct` and `answer`, you're comparing `"10" == 10` which is of course `False`. Thus you need to typecast the string `answer` into an `int` because `input` always returns a string. This results in `10==10` which is `True`.

Comment: I did not see you have already answered correctly. The edited code can be found in this ideone link: http://ideone.com/y3dPZC

Comment: Thank you @arsho! I'll leave it in the comments for him to see that way the post doesn't get cluttered.